# Find out if my data a series or data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

[image]

After seeing the result, I would assume that it is a series with hierarchical index.
Still I wasn't sure.
That's why I perform the following:

[image]

By seeing the above warning, I get a confirmation that it really is a series.
Still I'm asking myself, could I find it out without causing any error.
I mean is there any "pd.attribute" to find out if it's a Series or DataFrame?
Thank you in advance for any pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isinstance` i.e.

```
isinstance(ldata, pd.Series)
```

or `type` (which is a function, not a method of ldata) i.e.

```
type(ldata)
```

I tend to find the former more useful as you're generally trying to determine not just what the type is, but if it is of a specific type so you can take some action.

Answer (score 1):

Put in if..elif..else block:

```
if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
  # Dataframe
elif isinstance(data, pd.Series):
  # Series
else:
  # other type
```